# Calendars show "NaN" instead of "June"

Tags: angular, owl-date-time

Some owl-date-time calendars I'm using show "NaN" instead of June when implemented. I can't for the life of me figure this out, so at this point I'm just hoping someone else can tell me if they've had this bug before. Some of the calendars work and look almost identical, so any suggestions would be lovely.
thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your implementation

Comment: I will add that in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

In copying my implementation, I found that VScode had added autoformatted my code and added a "+" to the word June because the line was too long in the .ts file. Keep an eye out for this, I suppose.

Comment: The built-in VS Code JS/TS formatters should not do this; it was likely one of the extensions you have installed